# Print different page on link click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, hyperlink

I know this questions like this has been asked multiple times but I'm unable to figure out what's going wrong with my code

What I want to do is I want to click a link (with js) and print the contents of the link on the page without displaying.

Initially what I was trying to do is i'm putting my link (cart_receipt_path(id: @cart.id)) in link_to method and then trying to print it's contents from it's haml page being on the page i'm right not say home page

```
= link_to 'print', cart_receipt_path(id: @cart.id), :onclick => 'window.print();return false;', style: "display:none", class: "print_receipt_page"
```

```js
$('.print_receipt').click(function(){
      var text = $(this).text()
      if(text == "PRINT RECEIPT") {
        $(".print_receipt_page").click();
      }
    });
```

but what this is doing is it's just printing the home page instead of cart_receipt_path(id: @cart.id). So I found somewhere I need to put the page which I want to print in an iframe So I tried like this:

```
%iframe{:name => "frame", :src => "carts/receipt/#{@cart.id}", :style => "display:none;"}
%input{:onclick => "frames['frame'].print()", :type => "button", :value => "printletter", :class => "print_receipt_page"}/
```

But when I click on the button it's just priting a blank white page nothing on it and now the link **carts/receipt/#{@cart.id}** is being called everytime I refresh my home page.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about print content to the page with out displaying. Do you want to populate a invisible div or something

Comment: @MZaragoza like say earlier I had a button which takes me to a screen where I can view my receipt(different page) and then print it but now what I want is on clicking of button directly print the receipt.